# Error in opening an Access database in python

Tags: python, database, windows, ms-access, pyodbc

I am a new to python programming and i want to write a python program to read and write data to and from the database.

The connection code is as follows:

```
DNS='catalog'
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DSN=%s;' % (DRV,DNS))
```

catalog is the DSN name.

I am am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\exampes\xxx.py", line 8, in <module>
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DSN=%s;' % (DRV,DNS))
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning  Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x12b4 Thread 0x1544  DBC 0x567ea4 Jet'. (1) (SQLDriverConnect);
[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access  Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x12b4 Thread 0x1544 DBC 0x567ea4 Jet'. (1)"
```

Can anyone please help me..?

Comment: @Gord Thompson : I wonder how can a question asked two years ago could possibly duplicate of a question which was asked 7 days ago ??

Comment: I was trying to point future readers to a more complete answer to this question. (See my comment to the answer.) I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account under which you are running is not an administrator.  It needs registry access as per the message ([also described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295297))

Registry access is needed to find the ODBC driver for MS Access.

Comment: For future readers: This is only one possible cause of the error message, and a relatively uncommon one at that. Other causes and solutions are outlined in another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26317631/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

try to uncheck Attributes: Read-only box in file properties.